# ESP01 unsuccessful code execution

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266

I am trying to upload the Blink example from the Arduino IDE to a ESP8266-01 module using an Arduino Uno as serial programmer.
Now, the upload is successful but, upon restart (and disconnecting GPIO0 from GND), nothing happens. 
I have tried with different example sketches but it seems code was not uploaded.

My Board manager configuration

- Board: Generic ESP8266 Module
- Flash mode: QIO
- Flash frequency: 40 MHz
- CPU frequency: 80 MHz
- Flash size: 1M (128K SPIFFS)
- Debug port: Serial
- Debug level: none
- Reset method: ck (tried nodemcu too without success)
- Upload speed: 115200
- USB port

As an addition, here's what I get from the ESP01 through the Arduino IDE Serial monitor:

```
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v09f0c112
~ld
e:
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:3, boot mode:(3,7)

ets_main.c
```

and here's the IDE console window output:

```
sptool.py v1.3
Connecting..........
Auto-detected Flash size: 8m
Running Cesanta flasher stub...
Flash params set to 0x0020
Writing 229376 @ 0x0... 0 (0 %)1024 [...]
Wrote 229376 bytes at 0x0 in 39.0 seconds (47.0 kbit/s)...
Writing 229376 @ 0x10000... 0 (0 %)1024 [...]
Wrote 229376 bytes at 0x10000 in 39.0 seconds (47.0 kbit/s)...
Leaving...
```

The sketch I am using

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the LED_BUILTIN pin as an output
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
                                    // but actually the LED is on; this is because 
                                    // it is acive low on the ESP-01)
  delay(1000);                      // Wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
  delay(2000);                      // Wait for two seconds (to demonstrate the active low LED)
}
```

Comment: The standard blink example from the Arduino IDE uses pin 13. Have you modified it to use an equivalent pin on the ESP8266 to which a led has been attached ? You may also find that for uploading a sketch, it is necessary only to have GPIO0 pulled low during the reset/restart. Afterwards, you may then pull it high to load the sketch and run it.

Comment: Yes, I am using the LED_BUILTIN macro

Comment: try using `1` instead of the macro

Comment: @dandavis nothing, I have also tried to upload a different sketch for a Captive portal but code doesn't seem to be running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an ESP01 I don't think you should be using GPIO1 as the output pin, its my understanding that they don't have GPIO1.

I think they have GPIO0 and GPIO2, so you should have attached the LED to GPIO2 and use `digitalWrite(2, HIGH);` in you code.

Have a look at this page and see if what its on about is what you are trying to do.

http://iot-playground.com/blog/2-uncategorised/38-esp8266-and-arduino-ide-blink-example

Comment: I guess it may be better to use a sketch which writes to the serial console to see signs of life from it if the led method is not conclusive. Incidentally, connecting a Uno directly to the ESP01 (which the OP appears to be doing)  will result possibly in 5v at the ESP01 RX pin and some sort of level shifting is recommended.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I thought and apparently serial communication within the sketch is not working (the code was just sending a string over serial, no leds involved).

Comment: `GPIO1` is also known as TX, and on the ESP-01 it can be used as a digital output. Note that the blue on-board LED is also tied to `GPIO1`, as an inverted on-low configuration. You can't use `Serial.begin` if you use TX as an output.

Comment: I'm using this sketch: `void setup() { Serial.begin(9600); } void loop(){ Serial.println("Hello World!"); delay(1000); }`

Comment: @Anelito - 1. Are you connecting via Arduino? 2. Can you connect direct to PC/Mac? 3. Have you got a second ESP-01? 4. Are you using level shifting?

Comment: I am using an Arduino UNO as serial programmer (I have removed the Atmega) and a resistor-based level switch (2k and 1k). I have tried using esptool directly from command line and the output doesn't change. Unfortunately it's the only ESP module I got

Comment: Resistor based level switchers don't work for serial at 9600.  You can try 2400 baud, but are better off with a proper level shifter.

Comment: I know resistor switchers aren't the best choice but they worked when I was using the AT commands. I have tried with Serial and led sketches, so I believe there is a problem in uploading the code to the ESP or in running it.